# How can I set the position of my datagrid scrollbar in my winforms app?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

In my C# winforms app, I have a datagrid.  When the datagrid reloads, I want to set the scrollbar back to where the user had it set.  How can I do this?

EDIT:  I'm using the old winforms DataGrid control, not the newer DataGridView

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You don't actually interact directly with the scrollbar, rather you set the `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex`. So before it reloads, capture that index, once it's reloaded, reset it to that index.

**EDIT:** Good point in the comment. If you're using a `DataGridView` then this will work. If you're using the old `DataGrid` then the easiest way to do that is to inherit from it. See here: [Linkage](http://www.thescarms.com/dotnet/ScrollDataGrid.aspx)

The DataGrid has a protected GridVScrolled method that can be used to scroll the grid to a specific row. To use it, derive a new grid from the DataGrid and add a ScrollToRow method.

**C# code**

```
public void ScrollToRow(int theRow)
{
    //
    // Expose the protected GridVScrolled method allowing you
    // to programmatically scroll the grid to a particular row.
    //
    if (DataSource != null)
    {
        GridVScrolled(this, new ScrollEventArgs(ScrollEventType.LargeIncrement, theRow));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using the old DataGrid control

Comment: I am still using old DataGrid :) , the link answers it perfect. but i am afraid, the link won't last long, since its already more than 4 years old, i am reposting the answer here for future reference.

Comment: Those who need to know the index of the first visible `DataGrid` row: Please see my post below.

Answer (score 14):

Yep, definitely [FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedscrollingrowindex.aspx). You'll need to capture this value after some user interaction, and then after the grid reloads you'll want to set it back to the old value.

For instance, if the reload is triggered by the click of a button, then in the button click handler, you might want to have as your first line a command that places this value into a variable:

```
// Get current user scroll position
int scrollPosition = myGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;

// Do some work
...

// Rebind the grid and reset scrolling
myGridView.DataBind;
myGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = scrollPosition;
```

Answer (score 3):

Store your vertical and horizontal scroll values into some variable and reset them.

```
int v= dataGridView1.VerticalScrollingOffset ;
int h= dataGridView1.HorizontalScrollingOffset ;
//...reload
dataGridView1.VerticalScrollingOffset = v;
dataGridView1.HorizontalScrollingOffset =h;
```

Comment: HorizontalScrollingOffset and VerticalScrollingOffset has no setter

Comment: Works nevertheless (.NET 4.5.1 )

Comment: `VerticalScrollingOffset` is read-only (VB.NET 4.5.2) but `HorizontalScrollingOffset` was all I need and this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

---

you can save scroll position with next code

---

```
int Scroll;
void DataGridView1Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        Scroll = dataGridView1.VerticalScrollingOffset;
    }
```

---

and you can set scroll of dgv to same position after refresing, load dgv... with next code:

---

```
PropertyInfo verticalOffset = dataGridView1.GetType().GetProperty("VerticalOffset", BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
BindingFlags.Instance);
verticalOffset.SetValue(this.dataGridView1, Scroll, null);
```

Comment: All the User32.dll stuff does not work with DataGridView but your property magic works, thanks. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just posted the answer on the link given by [`BFree`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15861/bfree)

The DataGrid has a protected GridVScrolled method that can be used to scroll the grid to a specific row. To use it, derive a new grid from the DataGrid and add a `ScrollToRow` method.

C# code

```
public void ScrollToRow(int theRow)
{
    //
    // Expose the protected GridVScrolled method allowing you
    // to programmatically scroll the grid to a particular row.
    //
    if (DataSource != null)
    {
        GridVScrolled(this, new ScrollEventArgs(ScrollEventType.LargeIncrement, theRow));
    }
}
```

VB.NET code

```
Public Sub ScrollToRow(ByVal theRow As Integer)
    '
    ' Expose the protected GridVScrolled method allowing you
    ' to programmatically scroll the grid to a particular row.
    '
    On Error Resume Next

    If Not DataSource Is Nothing Then
        GridVScrolled(Me, New ScrollEventArgs(ScrollEventType.LargeIncrement, theRow))
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the answer by @BFree, but also needed to capture the first visible row in the `DataGrid`:

```
int indexOfTopMostRow = HitTest(dataGrid.RowHeaderWidth + 10, 
                                dataGrid.PreferredRowHeight + 10).Row;
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is an old question, Many of the solutions above did not work for me. What worked ultimately was:

```
if(gridEmployees.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex != -1) gridEmployees.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = 0;
```