# c# Scroll bars keep resetting when DataGridView updates

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, scrollbar

I am binding my grid as such:

`dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingSource();`

`dataGridView1.DataSource = tableData;` (tableData is an ArrayList of custom objects)

The dataSource is getting updated very often (the file it is reading from gets updated about every 2 ms). So when I am scrolling, the scrollbar will jump to it's original position upon a refresh. I refresh like this:

`((CurrencyManager)dataGridView1.BindingContext[tableData]).Refresh();` (this happens once every ~1 second)

How can I scroll without the scroll bar resetting every time the datagridview gets refreshed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378330/how-can-i-set-the-position-of-my-datagrid-scrollbar-in-my-winforms-app).  Although the question is about Winforms DataGrid, the answer is applies to DataGridView.  You need to store [FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedscrollingrowindex.aspx) before the reload and restore it after.

Comment: this seems to work. Given this is a very large data set, the scrolling is not very smooth. I can drag the bar a certain amount, and then it will stop following my cursor, so I have to go grab it again and repeat. Is this simply because it is very big, or because when it refreshes/handles row index, it stops the dragging motion?

Comment: Scrolling speed will depend on the hardware too.  You may try [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/188953-c%23-datagridview-doublebuffered-property/).  I have not used this so I am not sure if it actually works.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since you posted this question but I just ran into this kind of issue myself. One thing to check is to be sure you are ***not*** setting the **CurrentCell** property when your grid updates

Code such as the following will cause your scroll position to reset. You are telling it to view a particular row, and the first cell in that row.

```
YourGrid.CurrentCell = YourGrid[0, row];
```

Hope this helps.

DC