# Scrolling down a DataGridView control when bound to a data source causes user scrolling to stop. How can I avoid this?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that is constantly being rebound to a datasource.. once per second. Because of how the DGVs work, I have to manually record and reset the scroll position, sort column, and selected row during each refresh.   All of that is working fine.  However, when clicking and dragging the scrollbar, rebinding the data stops my scrolling.

For example, if I'm at the top of the DGV and I start scrolling down to the bottom, I may only get 1/2 the way down before it stops scrolling on its own.

Any ideas?

Comment: I found the answer on my own.  

http://stackoverflow.com/a/767603/1003916

Answer (score 0):

Please check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378330/how-can-i-set-the-position-of-my-datagrid-scrollbar-in-my-winforms-app) (The question is for DataGrid, but the answer is for both DataGrid/DataGridView)

> You don't actually interact directly with the scrollbar, rather you set the FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex. So before it reloads, capture that index, once it's reloaded, reset it to that index.
>   Source: [Anurag Ranjhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/884410/anurag-ranjhan)

Hopefully this helps! Have fun

---

## Edit

Based on your comment, perhaps this might help. Try this...

```
 Private Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
```

On refresh try to simulate the left mouse click at your current position. (up would cancel the state...that might be a good test)

```
mouse_event(&H2, 0, 0, 0, 0) 'down
mouse_event(&H4, 0, 0, 0, 0) 'up
```

You might beable to play with this and get it to recreate the drag state. Remember to add a reference to System.Runtime.InteropServices

Comment: I already have that part covered.  When I click and drag the scrollbar, it sort of becomes "attached" to my mouse cursor. When the DGV refreshes, it "detaches", so my scrolling is interrupted.