# Keeping a current list of running processes using a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, windows, datagridview, process

I'm trying to make a program similar to task manager in C#. My current method is to get a list of processes at application startup, then get a new list if the user presses the "update" button. I would like to keep a current list in my control instead, and "save" where the user has selected instead of the selection and the scroll bar being reset. What is a proper way of doing so in C#?

Here is how I currently update the control:

```
public void UpdateForm()
{
    processGridView.Rows.Clear();
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();

    for (int i = 0; i < processes.Length; ++i)
    {
        processGridView.Rows.Add();
        processGridView.Rows[i].Cells["processName"].Value = processes[i].ProcessName + ".exe";
        processGridView.Rows[i].Cells["processID"].Value = processes[i].Id;
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens when you use this code? You need to give errors for us to resolve. Besides that, this code looks fine.

Comment: The problem in this code is that if I try to run a timer to call this function on an interval, the DataGridView has a spasm and the cells readjust for no reason. The scroll bar is also reset, making it look all messed up. I need help figuring out how to refresh the list without resetting the whole control every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned in a comment that the real problem is with the refreshing of the `GridView`. I suggest you look at using [data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008361/how-can-i-refresh-c-sharp-datagridview-after-update).

**EDIT** a bit more code. But do read about data binding. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the msdn page about the DataSource property. Note that you don't need sql database object, you can bind to a simple list.

Then, when your timer ticks and you have new data, reset the grid view data and binding. I found that the reset also resets the scroll bar, so I added code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378330/how-can-i-set-the-position-of-my-datagrid-scrollbar-in-my-winforms-app) to keep the scroll offset fixed. It's not great because the mouse loses control of the scroll bar during refresh. I'll let you figure out a better solution.

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  OnRefreshGrid(null, null);
  Timer ticker = new Timer();
  ticker.Interval = 250;
  ticker.Tick += OnRefreshGrid;
  ticker.Start();
}

void OnRefreshGrid(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
  var table = new DataTable("Process List");

  Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();

  table.Columns.Add("Name");
  table.Columns.Add("Id");

  for (int i = 0; i < processes.Length; ++i)
  {
    table.Rows.Add(new object[] { processes[i].ProcessName + ".exe", processes[i].Id });
  } 

  table.AcceptChanges();
  source.DataSource = table;

  int scroll = dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;
  dataGridView1.DataSource = source;

  if (scroll != -1)
    dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = scroll;
}
```