# .net c# Can I link different DataGrid scrollbars?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I've found an answer that will let me set a row on a datagrid, although it seems a bit roundabout and hopefully unnecessary to do so - [setting position of datagrid scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378330/how-can-i-set-the-position-of-my-datagrid-scrollbar-in-my-winforms-app)

But before I go ahead and try to link my four DataGrids using this method (which I think is going to end up super messsy) I thought I'd ask - is there any way to neatly connect a scrollbar from one datagrid to another so that when I scroll down on Grid1 it'll scroll simultaneously on Grid2?

Assuming these grids will always have the same # of rows and columns

Or is there another way I should be constructing my views?!

Comment: Why isn't this one datagrid?

Comment: I needed four separate components so there'll be a left-hand-side (which has a fixed top and a dynamic bottom) and then a variable right hand side with the bottom component having x columns for each one column on the top (like merged cells in Excel I guess) and the right hand side should have many columns moving in and out, but always linked to the "parent" datagrids on the left